# Android: SMS and contacts data access

Tags: android

I'm trying to do a backup & restore application and I want to backup all SMS and all contacts informations. I read a lot about content providers but I first tried to copy these `contacts2.db` and `smsmms.db` files (the lazy and easiest way I figured out ) with no success because of permission issue (these databases are private). 
Now it seems like content providers remain my only issue. I thought about accessing each data field in both SMS and contacts, store it in files(XML format) with a specific structure, being easy to read and restore. 
Is that a good way? Are there any other easy ways instead of content providers for my backup & restore purpose?

Answer (score 0):

You need to access Content Providers

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

getting contacts is explained on that page but it doesn't mention sms, for sms use the Uri of content://sms (i think)

Comment: Ok. What's about data store. I would like to use XML files for structure purposes. Is that good?